# Unable to upload trigger files to S3 | Error while "amplify push"

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I cloned a project made some changes (In a backend function) and now when I'm trying to push. It's showing:

> Unable to upload trigger files to S3 An error occurred during the push
> operation: Unable to upload trigger files to S3

I'm using a separate environment.

The very first line of the error is:

> Invalid config /home/XXXXX/.amplify/awscloudformation/XXXXXXXXX
> at loadConfigFromPath

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Hi , did you solve it yet ?

Comment: **First:** Change the env of the project, env means the backend environment. change it to anything else or if you need to create a new env, or see an existing list of env first
`amplify env list` 
nowmove therewith:  
`amplify env checkout <env name>` 
and come back to your previous env.
and try to push again, It'll be solved most probably.
**Second:** My friend has a similar issue, he couldn't solve it with the previous approach. 
His problem was he has multiple Aws profiles and the one he was currently using didn't have the required permission.
So he just changed the profile.